# How to use map with multiple statements in the block

Tags: ruby

I'm taking a string and splitting it and then chaining map in.  I want any words that have a length of 5 letters or greater reversed.

If I do this

```
str.split(' ').map { |word| word}
```

it will return an array with all the words inside.

If I do this though

```
str.split(' ').map { |word| words; word.reverse if word.length >= 5 }
```

All I get back are the reversed words.  So how can I do both?

side note - I'm trying to be understand how to use blocks properly and while I've made some progress I'm still not completely fluent.

Comment: Can you give an input/output example?

Comment: Also, what is `words`?

Comment: "So how can I do both?" - what do you mean, "both"?

Comment: Input: `p spinWords( "Hey fellow warriors" )       # => returns "Hey wollef sroirraw" 
p spinWords( "This is a test")       # => returns "This is a test" 
p spinWords( "This is another test" )      # => returns "This is rehtona test"`     Output was: `["nil", "wollef", "sroirraw"]
["nil", "nil", "nil", nil"]
["nil", "nil", "rehtona", "nil"]`

Answer (score 6):

What about this one?

```
str.split.map { |word| word.length >= 5 ? word.reverse : word }
```

Comment: Yes,  that works.  I was just reading up on ternary operators earlier today but I didn't see it as a fit.  Now I know. Excellent!.

Comment: The reason why this works is that Ruby uses the result of the last statement as the return value of the block. The `if` statement was returning nils in one case. What you need is a construct returning a word no matter what (reversed or otherwise), and this is what the ternary does.

Answer (score 2):

```
str.split.map { |word| word.tap { |w| w.reverse! if w.length >= 5 } }
```

Using [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) on the word we always return a word itself, while it’s being reversed *inplace* when it’s long enough.

Your approach failed because postfix `if` implies returning `nil` when the condition is not met.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the my if statement.  This solution works as well.  I'll be reading up on tap.